# How to read a "string":int array into a HOCON Configuration?

Tags: java, hocon

So what I have is the below for a config.

```
"minecraft:blaze" {
"HOB Night" {
    # This Feature has not been Implemented yet
    "============Custom Drops============" {
        # True = Custom Drops, False = Vanilla
        "Enable Custom Drops: "=false
        # List out the Minecraft ID(ie. minecraft:Iron_sword) and the Number of them
        "List of Items and Amount"=
         "minecraft:dirt 5",
         "minecraft:stone 15"
    }
}
```

So what I have so far is this

```
ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getSpawnControl().getNode("minecraft:blaze", "HOB Night", "============Custom Drops============", "List of Items and Amount" ).getList(transformer)
```

however...i can't figure out how to get a 'transformer' into that portion of the getList feature...Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you let me advise. First of all you should rethink about your key configuration names. Two things are missing, properly close curly brackets and lists needs to be enclosed by square brackets. For instance:

```
"minecraft:blaze": {
  "HOB Night": {
    "============Custom Drops============": {
        "Enable Custom Drops: ": false,
        "List of Items and Amount": ["minecraft:dirt 5", "minecraft:stone 15"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. I'll do that but still need to grab those things thank you